# What is (!). in kdb and are below usecases valid to use it?

Tags: kdb

1. What is (!). called in kdb?
2. and are below use cases valid to use (!). to convert a list to a dictionary or are there better ways and other uses of (!). ?
   Example:

   ```
   q)(!). (`A`B;(`C`D`E;`F`G`H));
   q).[(!);flip (`A`B;`C`D;`E`F)]
   ```

I cannot find any documentation on the use cases on (!). in kdb tutorials. Please share any information on (!). and its uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a version of apply & yep your use case is valid. The reason the operator is wrapped in parentheses is because it itself is a dyadic infix operator as is dot apply (.)

If you attempt to apply it as is, your expression is like so, which Q doesn't like

```
// infixOp infixOp operand
q)+ . 4 5
'
  [0]  + . 4 5
        ^
```

Wrapping the operator within parentheses effectively transforms it so the expression now becomes

```
// operand infixOp operand
q)(+). 4 5
9
```

If you define a function which can't be used infix, then there's no need to wrap it

```
q)f:+
q)4 f 5
'type
  [0]  4 f 5
       ^
q)f . 4 5
9
```

If using apply with bracket notation as in your example, there's no need to wrap the function

```
q).[+;4 5]
9
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-index

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#parentheses-around-a-function-with-infix-syntax

Jason

Answer (score 3):

In terms of use-cases, I find it very useful when defining dictionaries/tables as configs particularly when dictionaries are too wide (horizontal) for the screen or when it's more useful to see fields/mappings vertically as pairs. From a code/script point of view that is.

For example:

```
mapping:(!) . flip(
 (`one;   1);
 (`two;   2);
 (`three; 3));
```

is much easier to read when scanning through a q script than

```
mapping2:`one`two`three!1 2 3
```

when the latter gets very wide.

It makes no difference to the actual dictionary of course because as Jason pointed out it's the same thing.